# Are 'related questions' automated or user contributed?

Tags: discussion, related-questions, site-crossover

Generally speaking I've found the '*related questions*' offered by the site when asking a question are either not related or only vaguely close to what is being asked.

I'm wondering if the chosen "related questions" are automated and identified via clever formulas and keywords or a combination of auto generated and *peer contribution*.

What I mean by 'peer contribution' is when an experienced user suggests a question is closely related, is a relationship built in the background to more accurately identify related questions in the future. Or, is it simply an automated process handled by some form of AI (I use the term AI loosely).

A genuine human is more capable of comprehending the gist of a question rather than a computer cherry-picking keywords, so I'm wondering how it is handled.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Word on the street is they use hamsters</s> It's automated. There is absolutely no way in *hell* that those were given by users. There are far too many questions, and not enough users that can be trusted to provide them.

*Real* user-contributed "related questions" would be in the comments.

Comment: You may add that users' recommendations are in "Linked" section next to "Related" (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191833/unable-to-bind-radiobutton-value-on-post-when-using-radiobutton-or-radiobuttonfo shows both)